# How do you control an html ordered list number from jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I currently have the following html which does not show the ordered list properly on IE7:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<style>
li {
  min-height: 20px;
}
</style>

<ol id='id-booking-steps'>
  <li>Stackoverflow</li>
  <li>Superuser</li>
  <li>Serverfault</li>
</ol>
```

The output looks like the following:

```
1. Stackoverflow
1. Superuser
1. Serverfault
```

If I remove the min-height, then everything is fine.  Assuming I can't touch the min-height, is there a way to make the number of an ordered list display properly by using jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this http://haslayout.net/css/No-Increase-on--ol--Numbers-Bug.

Apparently the fix is to add a `display : list-item` style to `li`. No jQuery needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   <ol>
    <li value="30"> makes this list item number 30.
    <li value="40"> makes this list item number 40.
    <li> makes this list item number 41.
    </ol>
```